# How do I remove node from Cloudera Manager using cm_api

Tags: python, api, automation, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am trying to remove host from Cloudera Manager 5.3.2 using cm_api 9.0.0

I tried

```
api.get_cloudera_manager().hosts_decommission([host])
api.get_cluster("cluster").remove_host(host)
```

but got error for remove_host()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cm_api/endpoints/clusters.py", line 218, in remove_host
return self._delete("hosts/" + hostId, ApiHostRef, api_version=3)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cm_api/endpoints/types.py", line 352, in _delete
api_version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cm_api/endpoints/types.py", line 380, in _call
api_version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cm_api/endpoints/types.py", line 139, in call
ret = method(path, params=params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cm_api/resource.py", line 124, in delete
return self.invoke("DELETE", relpath, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cm_api/resource.py", line 63, in invoke
headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cm_api/http_client.py", line 161, in execute
raise self._exc_class(ex)
cm_api.api_client.ApiException: ip-10-0-8-187.ec2.internal still has roles assigned to it. (error 400)
```

What is right sequence to remove host from Cluster or Is there one command in cm_api to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: The exception says the host still has roles assigned to it. Looks like you need to first remove the roles assigned to it.

Comment: What is the sequence to remove host from cloudera manager, is there any global command in cm_api ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact sequence has to be, but evidently one of them is to remove the roles from the host, so you'd want to do that first and go from there.

Comment: Perhaps the decommission step didn't complete.  Try adding a .wait() to it.

Answer (score 2):

This python script helps to remove the hosts from the cluster. The following are the steps:

1. stop and decommission all roles in a host
2. remove the roles from a host
    identify and delete the roles one by one
3. remove host from a cluster
4. remove host from cloudera manager

This script removes the hosts from the cloudera managed cluster running in aws. It is intend to scale down the worker node(node manager role) and gateway role from the cluster once there is no resource demand.

You can change the script accordingly based on your environment.

```
#!/bin/python
import httplib2
import os
import requests
import json
import boto3
import time
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "ACCESS_KEY"
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"] = "us-east-1"

region='us-east-1'
metadata = requests.get(url='http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id')
instance_id = metadata.text
host = requests.get(url='http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname')
host_id = host.text

username='admin'
password='admin'
cluster_name='cluster001'
scm_protocol='http'
scm_host='host.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
scm_port='7180'
scm_api='v17'



client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
ec2 = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name=region)

response = client.describe_auto_scaling_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id,])
state =  response['AutoScalingInstances'][0]['LifecycleState']
print "vm is in " + state 
if state == 'Terminating:Wait':
    print "host decommision started"
    ##decommission host
    service_url = scm_protocol + '://' +  scm_host + ':'  +  scm_port + '/api/' + scm_api + '/cm/commands/hostsDecommission'

    #service_url = scm_protocol + '://' +  scm_host + ':'  +  scm_port + '/api/' + scm_api + '/cm/hostsRecommission'
    #service_url = scm_protocol + '://' +  scm_host + ':'  +  scm_port + '/api/' + scm_api + '/cm/commands/hostsStartRoles'


    print service_url
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    req_body = { "items":[ host_id ]}
    print req_body
    req = requests.post(url=service_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), data=json.dumps(req_body), headers=headers)
    print req.text
    time.sleep(120)         

    ##delete roles in a host
    api_url = scm_protocol + '://' + scm_host + ':' + scm_port + '/api/' + scm_api + '/hosts/' + host_id
    req = requests.get(api_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
    a = json.loads(req.content)

    for i in a['roleRefs']:
        scm_uri='/api/' + scm_api + '/clusters/' + cluster_name + '/services/'+i['serviceName']+'/roles/'+i['roleName']
        scm_url = scm_protocol + '://' +  scm_host + ':'  +  scm_port + scm_uri
        print scm_url
        req = requests.delete(scm_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
        print req.text
        time.sleep(10)

    ##remove host from cluster
    service_url = scm_protocol + '://' +  scm_host + ':'  +  scm_port + '/api/' + scm_api + '/clusters/' + cluster_name + '/hosts/' + host_id
    print service_url
    req = requests.delete(service_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
    time.sleep(10)

    ##remove host from cloudera manager
    os.system("/etc/init.d/cloudera-scm-agent stop")    
    service_url = scm_protocol + '://' +  scm_host + ':'  +  scm_port + '/api/' + scm_api + '/hosts/' + host_id
    print service_url
    req = requests.delete(service_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
    print req.text
    time.sleep(10)

    ##refresh cluster configuration
    service_url = scm_protocol + '://' +  scm_host + ':'  +  scm_port + '/api/' + scm_api + '/clusters/' + 'commands/refresh'
    print service_url
    req = requests.post(service_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
    print req.text
    time.sleep(10)

    ##deploy client configuration
    service_url = scm_protocol + '://' +  scm_host + ':'  +  scm_port + '/api/' + scm_api + '/clusters/' + 'commands/deployClientConfig'
    print service_url
    req = requests.post(service_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
    print req.text
    time.sleep(10)
```